# Почему matcher возвращает false?

Tags: java, api, test-automation, rest-assured

имеется тест:

```
    @Test
    public void sixTest() {
        Specification.installSpec(Specification.requestSpec(), Specification.responseSpec());
        Response response = given()
                .when()
                .get("/api/unknown")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .extract().response();

        String value = response.path("data.color").toString();

        String patternString = "#[0-9A-Z]{6}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        assertTrue(matches);

    }
```

На выходе получаю matches false, почему? Ведь шаблон patternString соответствует полученному ответу. Т е в value содержится 6 значений из get запроса, дальше они проверяются на соответствие шаблона в matcher, но почему matcher возвращает false?

Вот responce:

```
{
    page: 1,
    per_page: 6,
    total: 12,
    total_pages: 2,
    data: [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "cerulean",
    year: 2000,
    color: "#98B2D1",
    pantone_value: "15-4020"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "fuchsia rose",
    year: 2001,
    color: "#C74375",
    pantone_value: "17-2031"
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Почему matcher возвращает false?*

Потому что метод [`Matcher::matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) проверяет *всю* строку целиком:

> public boolean matches​()
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.
> Returns:
> true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Если нужно найти *количество* совпадений, в Java 9 и выше можно выполнить такой код:

```java
String value = given()
                .when()
                .get("/api/unknown")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .extract().asString();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#[0-9A-Z]{6}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

assertEquals(6, matcher.results().count());
```

Comment: Мне нужно проверить, что строка color содержит цвет(строку формата #FFFFFF), насколько я понимаю, то проверка количества совпадений в шаблоне будет корректным решением. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Результат выполнения этого кода:

```
String value = response.path("data.color").toString();
```

будет массив всех найденных значений `data.color`.
В вашем примере их как минимум 2.
То есть, это будет строка типа `[#98B2D1, #C74375, ...]`.
Эта строка целиком не соответствует заданному регулярному выражению.